# How select greatest rows in each types

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

I have a table with PK("object", "type", "mid") and this structure:

```
+-----+----------+-------+---------+-----+
| type|  object  | value | preview | mid |
+-----+----------+-------+---------+-----+
| t1  | uid-0001 |   2   | p1      | 1   |
| t1  | uid-0002 |   10  | p2      | 1   |
| t2  | uid-0001 |   1   | p1      | 1   |
| t2  | uid-0003 |   5   | p3      | 1   |
| t3  | uid-0005 |   10  | p5      | 2   |
| t3  | uid-0001 |   40  | p1      | 2   |
| t4  | uid-0004 |   5   | p4      | 2   |
+-----+----------+-------+---------+-----+
```

The result I would like to achieve is:

```
+-----+----------+-------+---------+-----+
| type|  object  | value | preview | mid |
+-----+----------+-------+---------+-----+
| t1  | uid-0002 |   10  | p2      | 1   |
| t2  | uid-0003 |   5   | p3      | 1   |
| t3  | uid-0001 |   40  | p1      | 2   |
| t4  | uid-0004 |   5   | p4      | 2   |
+-----+----------+-------+---------+-----+
```

The SQL I have tried is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE value in (SELECT max(value) FROM table GROUP BY type) 
GROUP BY type
```

But this fails because it gets an incorrect value when it`s more than one identical value in table.

I have also tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value desc) x 
GROUP BY type;
```

but it has same error.

Example of incorrect results:

```
+-----+----------+-------+---------+-----+
| type|  object  | value | preview | mid |
+-----+----------+-------+---------+-----+
| t1  | uid-0002 |   10  | p2      | 1   |
| t2  | uid-0003 |   5   | p3      | 1   |
| t3  | uid-0005 |   10  | p5      | 2   |
| t4  | uid-0004 |   5   | p4      | 2   |
+-----+----------+-------+---------+-----+
```

In this case rows for `t3` and `t1` used same value (10, that must be for t1) and selected it in both types (t1, t3);

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt is really close, you just need to add a where clause to your subquery to link it to the outer query, rather than use `GROUP BY`, the following will get your desired results:

```
SELECT t.Type, t.Object, t.Value, t.Preview 
FROM Table AS t
WHERE value IN (SELECT max(value) FROM Table AS t2 WHERE t2.Type = t.Type) 
ORDER BY t.Type;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd8557/1)**

If you are using a more recent version of MySQL (8.0) you can also use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number):

```
SELECT t.Type, t.Object, t.Value, t.Preview
FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Value DESC) AS rowNumber
      FROM Table) AS t
WHERE t.RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY t.Type;
```

**[Example on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2e4ea6dc0f79c86514279d9da277cba7)**

Comment: Thanks! it`s helped me, but for now i cant add you +rep. I`ll back when get 15.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table with just the type and max value for each type, then use that table as a filter to only see the records with the max value

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        type
        ,MAX(value) as max_value
    FROM table
    ) m on t.type = m.type and t.value = m.max_value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query for the optimal solution & make sure the data type of "Value" column should be "Number".

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE (type,VALUE) IN (SELECT type,MAX(value) FROM table GROUP BY type)
```

Comment: Has a duplicate as a result of having the same values ​​in the value field

Comment: You will not face any issue in case of same values in the value field.